# Sending Username and permissions from login to menu c#

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio

Hello guys i'm trying to send "Username" and "Permissions" from Login form to Menu form. here is the code i'm having issue with. Thanks in advance

this is for the login:-

```
 OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT UserName, Permisions  FROM Employee WHERE      (UserName = '" + textBox1.Text + "')  AND ([Password] = '" + textBox2.Text + "') ", con);

        DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {

            this.Hide();
            var p = new p(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(), dt.Rows[0][1].ToString());
            p.Closed += (s,args) =>
            this.Close();
            p.ShowDialog();

        }
```

This is for the other form (p)

```
public partial class p : Form
{
    public p(string UserName, Permisions)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Label1.Text = UserName;
        Label2.Text = Permisions;


    }
```

Comment: OK, so whats the actual issue?

Comment: Your problem might be that Little Bobby Tables is trying to log in.

Comment: Is this just an MVCE or are you really allowing unaltered user input into your database strings? You might want to read about SQL Injection if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

i'm stupid i found out that i didnt add string to Permisions in P form

Comment: probably better to delete the question if it was a simple missing element